# XSLT Debugging: "The stylesheet is too complex." XsltException

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xslt

When I try to debug an XSLT file using Visual Studio 2010, I get the following popup:

```
---------------------------
Transform Error
---------------------------
XSL Transformation failed. See Output Window for details.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Once I click OK the following appears in the output window in VS2010:

```
XsltException
-------------
The stylesheet is too complex.
```

The XSL stylesheet I'm using has 1881 lines (~68KB). I tried breaking it up using 10 imports (about 275 lines each), but I get the same error. This doesn't happen for any of my other stylesheets (my next biggest stylesheet is about 300 lines and <16KB).

NOTE: **This does -not- happen in Visual Studio 2008. I'm using this as a temp fix.**

NOTE 2: I found a Windows Support Page about how `format-number()` might be causing an error, but I've installed all service packs and it didn't change anything. (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/832757)

Comment: Remove each of the exports one by one until you find the problem.